# Plotting multidimensional data on a graph

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a data which has 1700 rows, each with 9 features of houses and an array holding the prices corresponding to those features. I have built a linear regression model on this data, but I would like to visualize it. Can I somehow convert these 9 features into single feature using PCA? I have tried this but I still get error saying that x, y need to be of same size.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
pca = PCA(n_components = 9)
# features contains 1700 rows of 9 feature data, y contains 1700 price values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, y)
pca.fit(x_train)
x_train = pca.transform(x_train)
x_test = pca.transform(x_test)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
pred = clf.predict(x_test)
plt.scatter(x_train, y_train)
plt.show()
```

Error occurs at plt.scatter() function, feature.shape = (17000, 9), y.shape = (17000, 1)

Comment: At what line does the error show up? Also, the shapes of the arrays would be helpful

Comment: @Varsha error shows at 'plt.scatter(x_train, y_train)' line. Shape of 'features' : (17000, 9), shape of 'y': (17000, 1)

Comment: try setting n_components to 1 the resulting output of pca will then be a single feature.

Comment: @error I see, thank you very much

Comment: @error Please make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is due to the unequal shapes of the inputs for `plt.scatter`. `x_train` is an array with 17000 rows and 9 columns. Whereas `y_train` is an array of 17000 rows and one column.

You can fix that error by either indexing `x_train` and only select a single column form it.

`x_train[:,0]` selects the first column of `x_train`.

An alternative approach is to set `n_components` to 1. the n_components determines how many features `pca` returns. Setting it to 1 returns 1 setting it to 9 returns 9.

Comment: I though n_features stood for the amount of features I was having and I incorrectly set it to 9, where it should have been one